# How to enable customer user for existing contact using apex?

Tags: contact, user, community, user-registration

For the community self registration page if the user enters the detail, I want to check if the contact already exist on the basis of email entered by user. If it does, I want to create user for that existing contact. How can  achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution.I have Prepared the User record data using the Contact details.Then call the`Site.createPortalUser(user, accountId, password, sendEmailConfirmation)`  method to create the user.It is working fine.

Comment: So You are just setting up contact Id on newly created user Like new User(ContactId = exisitngContact.Id); and the pass that user to createPortalUser method??

Comment: @pepper42 Yes, I have posted the sample code in the Salesforce developer community.You can find the sample code from the link https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000IA5FQAW